# Is there a limit to how tall my Tower can be?

Tags: tiny-tower

I am getting closer to 100 floors now, and that got me wondering. Is there a maximum number of floors my tower can have? Or can I keep building floors for essentially forever?

Comment: I'm at 169 floors. And I haven't spent any more than $10 since I started. Just be patient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *suspect* that there is a maximum of 152 floors in Tiny Tower.  This is because there are (as of v1.5) 57 different residential floors + 95 commercial floors.  Every time I build a new floor, I get a residential or commercial floor that I don't already have.

Comment: Did anyone hit the cap yet ?

Comment: I got 158 floors, there's no hard limit as far as I can tell, but like JohnRegner said, there's a limit for the floor types - you can only built empty floors once you've exhausted each type

Answer (score 16):

There doesn't appear to be a limit to the number of floors...but there is a limit to the number of floors that **have anything in them**.

*(Based on v2.0 numbers...)*

```
   1 Lobby Floor
+ 63 Residential Floors
+105 Commercial Floors (21 of each of the 5 types)
   =
 169 "Useful" Floors
```

However, you **can** keep constructing additional floors beyond this. You just won't be able to turn them into anything - when you pick Residential or any of the Commercial types, the game will tell you that you've maxed out that floor type.

It's up to you whether you want to blow away millions of coins to add unusable floors from 170 onward or not.

Comment: +1 Confirm. You can always have the floors ready for a future update when they might add new types...

Comment: @JohnoBoy My latest edit covers through 1.5.2 - they added 1 of each type of commercial floor and 3 new residential floors.

Comment: Really? only 1 of each? I managed to to add a couple of residential's so I figured they added more. Oh well

Answer (score 3):

The official number given by [NimbleBit](http://support.nimblebit.com/customer/portal/articles/683975-maximum-number-of-floors) (emph mine):

> There are currently 87 residential floors and 29 floors of each business type. Once you have all **232 unique floors**, you can continue to build empty floors.  We may add more floors in the future but do not have any plans at this time.

Just as they say here, and the [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/51820/80141) by JohnRegner, you can continue building empty rooms.

Answer (score 0):

I am now on Floor 186. There is no limit in sight. Already, I have 17 extra floors, meaning they will probably remain empty for several years. Take this as a warning, and stop and save your coins when you reach 169. It's too late for me, but not for you!

Answer (score -3):

There are only over 200 floors. 251 to be exact.

Comment: Ttttt? Haha great name!

Comment: Yupperdoodledoos

Comment: Do you have a source for this, preferably authoritative?  Why 251 instead of 250, 255, or 256, all of which make more sense.