# What is the maximum number of floors to be reached in Tiny Towers

Tags: tiny-tower

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a limit to how tall my Tower can be?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48916/is-there-a-limit-to-how-tall-my-tower-can-be)

I have 165 floors in Tiny Tower and would like to know what the maximum is?